# Problems with coordinates after rotating in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have problems to draw some rects in canvas.

My goal is to draw this one:
https://ibb.co/b6Hsc4w

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
0    
1    X X X
2    X   X
3    X X X
4
5
```

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 400;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Line(x, y, length, height, angle, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.length = length;
    this.height = height;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.color = color;

    this.draw = function () {
        c.save();

        c.translate(this.x, this.y);
        if (this.angle > 0) {
            c.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
        }

        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fillRect(0, 0, this.length, this.height);

        c.restore();
    };
    this.draw();
}

new Line(2, 1, 3, 1, 0, "black");
new Line(4, 1, 3, 1, 90, "green");
new Line(4, 3, 3, 1, 180, "red");
new Line(2, 3, 3, 1, 270, "blue");
```

but using the code I receive:
https://ibb.co/vwRX1sG

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
0    X
1    X X X
2  X X X  
3      X 
4
5
```

It's like the source point is not working correctly.

HTML only contains a canvas element and I'm not using any special library.

Comment: Please add some relevant tags like html and JavaScript, and also the libraries you are using in the code.

Comment: You need to recalculate the point where the new line begins. The first line begins at 2 and ends at 2+3=5 (where 2 is the x and 3 is the width) So the second line need to be `new Line(5, 1, 3, 1, 90, "green");`

Comment: @kennyzx
Html only contains a canvas element and I'm not using any special library.

Comment: @enxaneta

But, if you open the second link, you can see that the second line would start at x4 not x5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are rotating on the corners of the blocks, instead of the centers. Below I have added 0.5 to the first transform and then subtracted it in a second transform after the rotation. You can see it working here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mksxtcwq/)

```
function Line(x, y, length, height, angle, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.length = length;
    this.height = height;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.color = color;

    this.draw = function () {
        c.save();

        c.translate(this.x+0.5, this.y+0.5);
        if (this.angle > 0) {
            c.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
        }
        c.translate(-0.5, -0.5);

        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fillRect(0, 0, this.length, this.height);

        c.restore();
    };
    this.draw();
}

new Line(2, 1, 3, 1, 0, "black");
new Line(4, 1, 3, 1, 90, "green");
new Line(4, 3, 3, 1, 180, "red");
new Line(2, 3, 3, 1, 270, "blue");
```